# How can I change background colors of even divs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have problem with changing color of my *divs*.

I dont know how to have other background color of even *div*, whose each is in *li* element.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="demo1">
    <div class="d">
      COLOR BLUE
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="demo1">
    <div class="d">
      COLOR RED
    </div>
  </li>
   .
   .
   .
</ul>
```

I tried to use *:nth-child* but its not working at all (I only typed class name of *div*).

Comment: The CSS selector your are looking for is `:nth-child(even)`

Comment: from you markup, it ends up to be : `.demo1 div.d {background:blue;} .demo1:nth-child(even) div.d {background:red;}` https://jsfiddle.net/athzj0s4/

Comment: this link will useful for you please check 
 https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you use `even` with your code..

```css
ul li > div {
  background: blue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) > div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="demo1">
    <div class="d">
      COLOR BLUE
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="demo1">
    <div class="d">
      COLOR RED
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="demo1">
    <div class="d">
      COLOR BLUE
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="demo1">
    <div class="d">
      COLOR RED
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass `even` or `odd` in your css

```
mydiv:nth-child(even){
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}

p:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>RED.</p>
<p>Blue</p>
<p>Red</p>
<p>Blue</p>

</body>
</html>
```

You Can Use odd & even like that

Comment: it's about the div inside li ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
mydiv:nth-child(1n) {
     background: red;

 }
mydiv:nth-child(2n) {
    background: green;

}
```

another way

```
mydiv:nth-child(even){
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select the :nth-child of the list-item and target the div within it:

Example: https://codepen.io/Albyzai/pen/JjNbNxG

HTML

```
 <ul>
  <li>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  
}

.d {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

li:nth-child(even) div {
  background: red;
}
```